# Why doesn't the link open to another page in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

HEADER.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <header className='header'>

      <div className='left-section'>
        <img src={CustomLogo} alt='Logo' className='logo' />
        <nav className='nav'>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink to='/'>Homepage</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to='/about'>About Me</NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

ABOUTME.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
const AboutMe: React.FC = () => {
  console.log('About Me component rendered')
  return (
    <div>
      <p>HELLOOOO!!!!</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default AboutMe
```

HOME.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header'


  return (
    <div className='page-container'>
      <Header />
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

APP.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import AboutMe from './pages/AboutMe/Aboutme'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<AboutMe />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './pages/Home/Home'
import '../src/index.css'

const root = document.getElementById('root')!
const rootElement = createRoot(root)
rootElement.render(
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>
)
```

I've tried in every way, with BrowserRouter, with Switch, in every possible manner. The console doesn't show any errors, and it doesn't even print the console.log, so there's simply no link. What can I do? P.S.: I removed some unnecessary parts of the code.

Comment: There should be ***at least*** one invariant error regarding the `App` component rendering another `BrowserRouter` component inside the router that `index.tsx` renders. Other than this I don't see any other problem or issue with the code you have shared. Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly the problem is you have?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that the `Home.tsx` snippet appears to be incomplete. I'm sure it's just a typo copy/pasting to the post, but can you [edit] to include correct and complete code in your [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

You are using `Router` for the index and APP files you need to use it once.

I don't see any other issue in your code. if this didn't work please add a comment or add more context.

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding `exact={true}` to the first `<Route />` to fix the issue.

Alternatively, switch the order of the `<Route />` tags so that the shorter path comes last.

Comment: Just FYI, in React-Router v6, the [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) component hasn't any `exact` prop, and routes are *always* exactly matched (*a [Route Ranking System](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) is used*), so route order is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah!  @Drew Thanks for that.  I'm in the process of upgrading to v6...my head hurts.  And the 6.4 stuff didn't make things any easier.

Comment: V6 introduced a ton of new and different routing patterns, I had to really unlearn much of the older v4/5 habits.

Answer (score -3):

React uses a practice called an SPA which stands for Single Page Accessibility. It means react doesn't load a new page but it refreshes each time and uploads new components.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
```

instead use

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
```

also check if home needs to appear twice

```
import App from './pages/Home/Home'
```

Check thoroughly the nesting used to import components in your app.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What? SPA stands for Single-Page Application.